# How to call a javascript function from external link file in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, url, external, typescript-typings

I am working on an app with angular 4, and I have a function in javascript to call from my component

The external javascript file is a link file

So To call the javascript file, I did the following code:

```
const body = <HTMLDivElement> document.body;
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerHTML = '';
    script.src = 'https://sase.wde.de/dedesa/name.file.js';
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    body.appendChild(script);
```

It works fine until that, then I call the function this way

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    loadFoo();
  }

export default function loadFoo(): void {

  const lastname = "dedee";
  const firstname = "dede";
  const mail = "ede@dede.d";
  const mdn = "55662";
  const siteweb = "dede.html";
  const token = "dededede";
  const date = "2018-05-29 14:03:57";
  const webPage = "dedesz";

  startNAmeNoReg(lastname, firstname, mail, mdn, webPage, token, siteweb, date);
  startNAmePush(lastname, firstname, mail, mdn, webPage, token, siteweb, date);
}
```

When i call the function, it gives me the error

> ERROR ReferenceError: startNAmeNoReg is not defined

Comment: Have you tried using `import`?

Comment: `import * as xJS from './x.js';` like that ? can't do it since the js file is in http

Comment: You need to have a module in order to be able to use those functions.

Comment: Where is `startNAmeNoReg` defined, and is it really capitalized that way?